# Running C++ app from C# process running on Mono. run-detectors error

Tags: c#, c++, linux, mono

I'm currently working on porting a tool to Linux. I'm using mono to to this, and have got the main tool running. However, this tool calls another program, which is written in C++ and compiled natively on Linux with g++. I've had a lot of difficulty porting this over, but have it working and running (runs as expected with ./othertool.exe).

However, when trying to run the original tool on Mono, it fails at launching the other tool, giving a error.

```
run-detectors: unable to find an interpreter for .../othertool.exe
```

I'm not sure why this happens, as when testing with a hello world, I managed to get a C++ program running by calling it from C# on Mono. I'm running the other tool using the Process class (see code) which works fine with the hello world example.

```
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = baseDir +
                   Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +
                   "tools" +
                   Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +
                   "othertool.exe",
        Arguments = arguments.ToString(),
        UseShellExecute = false
    }
};

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Anyone know why this happens? Google does not yield anything so I guess this might not be common. Feel free to ask for more information or clarity, as I've probably left something out.

Comment: Use `mono` as your `filename` and pass the CIL based (exe) assembly as an argument

Comment: It's not CIL, the other tool is compiled natively on linux with g++. I've added this in the question.

Comment: `othertool.exe` is a native c++/c executable? Do you have an `.exe` kernel/shell extension registered? If so, try removing the `.exe` extension from the file.

Comment: That makes no difference. The hello world example ran fine with the c++ program compiled to a `.exe`.

Comment: What does `file othertool.exe` report?

Comment: Ok so turns out that I was somehow using the Windows built version of othertool instead of the Linux one. Who let that happen? Runs 'fine' when using the correct one. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Cool, run-detectors/interpreter failures usually (always?) are related to PE executable (`.exe`) issues (and other non-Linux binaries), assuming you are on a Linux disto (like Ubuntu) that support launching PE format but without something like Wine installed, you will get a failure. IMHO: Naming non-PE/non-CIL files as an `.exe` is bad-form on Linux...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so turns out that I was somehow using the Windows built version of othertool instead of the Linux one. Who let that happen? Runs 'fine' when using the correct one. – Cameron

Cool, run-detectors/interpreter failures usually (always?) are related to PE executable (`.exe`) issues (and other non-Linux binaries), assuming you are on a Linux disto (like Ubuntu) that support launching PE format but without something like Wine installed, you will get a failure. IMHO: Naming non-PE/non-CIL files as an `.exe` is bad-form on Linux...
                    – SushiHangover